# Elegant way of creating list from character expression in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of months, like shown below, where the months will `always` be separated by hyphen.

```
l = ['201701-201703', '201801-201804']
```

I want to expand the list to include every `months` in between this range.

**Desired output should be**:

```
['201701','201702','201703','201801','201802','201803','201804']
```

*My solution:*

```
l1 = [[str(a) for a in list(map(lambda x:x+int(i[0:6]),list(range(abs(eval(i))+1))))] for i in l]
print(l1)
    [['201701', '201702', '201703'], ['201801', '201802', '201803', '201804']]

# Flatten the list
l2 = [item for sublist in l1 for item in sublist]
print(l2)
    ['201701', '201702', '201703', '201801', '201802', '201803', '201804']
```

My solution is very cumbersome to read and will fail when range spans over multiple years. **Can someone suggest a code which is simpler to read and understand?**

**Update:** If the end result are dates, that's also fine.

Comment: Given that you already have a fairly lean and working solution, you might instead to post this on our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You should be using `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date` objects to work with dates, not strings

Comment: Also note, your calls to `list` are unnecessary

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was thinking something similar.

Comment: Please reconsider the usage of "eval" in your code.. It's a security concern.

Comment: @Cedric Sure, please propose better solution. My solution is quite bad. I am looking forward to it.

Comment: Can we always assume that it will be monotonically increasing for each list element?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Oh yes, but only within a range.

Comment: My idea is to get the difference between the left and right element after a split, then for each list element on the first split and subtract one from the difference until its 0. Then flatten. Solves the error if the two elements are the same also. Can't provide a solution right now, but I hope this points you to a right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it is more readable.

I increased the size of the second expression by 5 characters, but reduced the size of the first one by 26 characters.

Deleted `map()`, `list()`, `abs()`, `lambda`, `eval()`. Introduced `split()`, `enumerate()`.

```
l = ['201701-201703', '201801-201804']
l1 = [range(*[int(v)+i for i,v in enumerate(e.split('-'))]) for e in l]
print(l1)
l2 = [str(item) for sublist in l1 for item in sublist]
print(l2)
```

output:

```
[range(201701, 201704), range(201801, 201805)]
['201701', '201702', '201703', '201801', '201802', '201803', '201804']
```

**UPDATE1**

This modification to jump the border of the year.

```
l = ['201711-201802', '201901-201904']
l1 = [range(*[int(v)+i for i,v in enumerate(e.split('-'))]) for e in l]
print(l1)
l2 = [str(item) for sublist in l1 for item in sublist if 0 < item % 100 < 13]
print(l2)
```

output:

```
[range(201711, 201803), range(201901, 201905)]
['201711', '201712', '201801', '201802', '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904']
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It was quite close to my thinking and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd approach this using `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['date'])

# split start and end date into two columns and parse as datetime
df_ = df.date.str.split('-', expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y%m')

# add MonthEnd -> this will ensure that the last month is included in the range
df_[1] = df_[1] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

# use pd.daterange to generate the range with a frequence of a month
(df_.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(*x, freq='1M', closed='right'), axis=1)
                                    .explode()
                                    .dt.strftime('%Y%m')
                                    .values.tolist())

# ['201701', '201702', '201703', '201801', '201802', '201803', '201804']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
[ str(q) for p in l for q in range(int(p[:6]), int(p[7:])+1) ]
```

However, this doesn't work for ranges starting in one year and ending in the next. For that you can do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

l = ['201701-201703', '201801-201804', '201701-201804']

res_list = []
for p in l:
    d1 = datetime.strptime(p[:6], '%Y%m')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(p[7:], '%Y%m')
    while d1 <= d2:
        res_list.append(d1.strftime('%Y%m'))
        d1 += relativedelta(months=1)

res_list
```

Output:

```
['201701',
 '201702',
 '201703',
 '201801',
 '201802',
 '201803',
 '201804',
 '201701',
 '201702',
 '201703',
 '201704',
 '201705',
 '201706',
 '201707',
 '201708',
 '201709',
 '201710',
 '201711',
 '201712',
 '201801',
 '201802',
 '201803',
 '201804']
```

You can do the same with list comprehension, but it isn't elegant anymore. But just for fun, here you go:

```
[ str(date)
  for d1, d2 in map(lambda p: map(int, p.split("-")), l) 
  for year_offset in range((d2 - d1)//100 +1)
  for date in range(max(d1, 100*(d1//100 + year_offset) +1 ), 
                    min(d2, 100*(d1//100 + year_offset) +12) +1) ]
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I am looking for a generic solution.